# Remove object from array if it is contained in another array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to remove an object from an array, if that object's property (unique) is included in the other array. I know I can do a nested for-loop like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
        if(array[i].Email === array2[j].Email) {
            //remove array[i] object from the array
        }
    }
}
```

Or whatever. Something like that. Is there an ES6 filter for that? I can easily do a filter up against a regular array with strings, but doing it with an array of objects is a bit more tricky.

Comment: Can you share sample arrays?

Comment: ES6 filter? Do you mean [ES5 filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)?

Comment: @Rajesh Object has an "Email" property. That should be fine.

Comment: Are you trying to delete the key, remove the value/ reference or remove the value from memory?

Comment: @evolutionxbox ECMAScript is probably what I should call it. I still haven't figured the difference out.

Comment: ECMA is the name for the standard (or spec) which JS adheres to. ES6/ES2015 and ES5 are just versions of that spec.

Comment: @Undefined I'm trying to remove it from the original array (or simply return an array without the duplicates).

Comment: Is use of array mandatory? could you use javascript object?

Comment: @ronIDX I already have an array of objects, so yeah it's pretty damn mandatory.

Comment: Hoping I undestand correctly your question, couldn't you transform array in Object, where each key is email and value is the whole element? So you can access item directly, without iterating every item. To check if item is in Object, just check if ObjectFromArray.Email != undefined.

Comment: @ronIDX How would something like that look? "transform array in Object" is not something you can do. "each key is email and value is the whole element" wouldn't do anything, except take a lot more time to do. Transforming the array into 1 object would still be just as slow. But give me a JSFiddle example and I'll look at it.

Comment: Sure, here's the codepen [object as array](http://codepen.io/grimaldello/pen/NRLQVP). Here you iterating each array only one time, then you can access element directly. Obviously I hope I understand correctly your question.

Comment: @ronIDX What I want to do is remove all duplicates from my Array1 if they exist in Array2. I need to do it fast and I need to return the new array. I don't need to search through the array at any given time. I don't need anything but remove duplicates and return the new array. Yours would be very slow.

Comment: mmm two nested for loop should be O(n^2), complexity increases with the power of 2 with the number of elements.... mine should be 2n for create object as array, plus another n for searching duplicate (that I addedo to the [codepen](http://codepen.io/grimaldello/pen/NRLQVP) and O(n^2) should be more complex than O(2n+n). But I ended my study years ago, so maybe I'm wrong :)

Comment: I updated the [codepen](http://codepen.io/grimaldello/pen/NRLQVP) adding some performance test. In all my testcases objectAsArray() function is faster than nestedFor(), I put the duplicate as last element thus the worst case for nestedFor() function. Try to increase element and performance difference should increment in favour of objectAsArray()

Comment: @ronIDX Your "object as array" is roughly 80-100% slower (0.45 for yours and 0.25 for nested) on my end. It sure is faster than the `.filter` ones, but nested for-loop is definitely fastest as far as I can see.

Comment: Dunno what you test, but codepen for me print this result: "Nested For: 6.07000000000005" "Object as array: 0.5850000000000364",times is slower nested.  You check every item in array1(10 elements) and array2(10 elements), worst case 100 iteration. With mine you have 10 iteration for array1 + 10 iteration for array2 + 10 iteration (in worst case) for the duplicate check, total 30 iteration. However do what fits best for you

Comment: @ronIDX That's very odd. I get the same results in Codepen, but running it locally or in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nd4t18st/) I get: `Nested For: 0.2699999999999545` and `Object as array: 0.35499999999995` (after running a few times).

Comment: Yeah really strange. Changing browser also change time performance. Maybe there's something that browser do under the hood

Comment: @ronIDX Or because Codepen compiles it differently or something.

Comment: JSFiddle use browser console. Try open your fiddle in firefox and you see different results from chrome or safari...

Comment: @ronIDX It should use browser console. That's what `console.log()` is there for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not very optimal, but try this

```
array = array.filter( function( item ){
  return array2.filter( function( item2 ){
    return item.Email == item2.Email;
  }).length == 0;
});
```

Try with `find` as well, it won't iterate all the elements and will break after first match itself

```
array = array.filter( function( item ){
  return array2.find( function( item2 ){
    return item.Email == item2.Email;
  }) == undefined;
});
```

Comment: Yeah that works. Thanks! Is that the best way, though? I'm assuming the fastest would be O(n^2) anyway?

Comment: @Snorlax fastest way would be to index unique email-ids from both arrays and then match each item one by one. In that case, complexity would O(2n)

Comment: Yeah. With < 10 items, this should be fast enough though.

Comment: @Snorlax with less than 10 items, there shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: I would suggest you use `array.findIndex` or `array.find` or `array.some`. We do not need to find all elements and should break upon first match

Comment: @Rajesh yes, if this is supposed to be used on server-side NodeJs environment then `find` will be optimal but for the browser environment only latest ones have support for `find`, so would stick to `filter` only.

Comment: @gurvinder372 OP is ready accept ES6 answers, which means he has a layer(webpack/babel...) to compile it. Also he mentioned on Nina's answer, he is using typescript. So I guess you can use `.find`

Comment: @Rajesh I'm simply running it in the browser as Javascript. Not compiling any ECMAScript to Javascript or anything like that.

Comment: In that case, use `array.filter` and not `.find`. As mentioned by gurvinder, it has compatibility issues.

Answer (score 10):

If you are fine using ES6, you can even look into `array.find`, `array.filter` or `array.some`

#### [Array.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

```js
var result = array.filter(x=>{
  return array2.findindex(t=> t.Email === x.Email) === -1
})
```

#### [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
var result = array.filter(x=>{
  return !array2.some(t=> t.Email === x.Email)
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) with ES6

```
var array = [/* your data */],
    array2 = [/* your data */],
    set = new Set(...array2.map(a => a.Email));

array = array.filter(a => !set.has(a.Email));
```

Comment: Doesn't look like my Typescript validation is happy about Set.. hmm.

Comment: es6 !== typescript.

Comment: I never said that it was.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one.... :)

```
if(array[i].Email === array2[j].Email){
   // splice(Index you want to remove,to witch element)
   array1.splice(i,1);
}
```

splice() can remove element of your array. You need to pass witch element. witch element is the start of delete. How many elements should delete. That's 1.. :)

Comment: n.. no. That's not what I want.

Answer (score -1):

How about writing a function, passing the parameters and simply collecting the output?

```js
function arrNotInArrKey(arr1, arr2, key) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
      if (arr1[i][key] === arr2[j][key]) {
        arr1.splice(i, 1);
        i--;
      }
    }
  }
  return arr1;
}
console.log(
  arrNotInArrKey([{
    name: 1
  }, {
    name: 3
  }, {
    name: 2
  }], [{
    name: 2
  }], "name")
);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
You can use shift function. here it's example.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_array_shift
for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
        if(array[i].Email === array2[j].Email) {
            array.shift(array[i].Email);
        }
    }
}
```