# How to remove items in one array if other has it?

Tags: arrays, typescript, object

How to remove item from array B if array A has it. I want to iterate through by ID.

array A: it has all the items

```
[{
"Name":"John", 
"Id":1
},
{
"Name":"Peter", 
"Id":2
},
{
"Name":"Phillip", 
"Id":3
},
{
"Name":"Abby", 
"Id":4
},
{
"Name":"Don", 
"Id":5
}]
```

array B: has just the selected items

```
[{
"Name":"John", 
"Id":1
},
{
"Name":"Abby", 
"Id":4
}]
```

I want to remove from array A John and Abby by Id, because they are in array b.

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
   if (b[i].Id == ta[i].Id) {
      for (var j = 0; j < b[j]; j++) {
              a.splice(i, 1);
      }
   }
}
```

this is not working as I thought

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove object from array if it is contained in another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40082663/remove-object-from-array-if-it-is-contained-in-another-array)

Answer (score 0):

You could first get all id's of person objects in `b`:

```
let idsInB: number[] = b.map(person => person.Id); // > [1, 4]
```

This array of id's can be used to filter `a`, and then assign the result back to `a`. Let's contain that in a function `cleanA`:

```
function cleanA(): void {
    let idsInB: number[] = b.map(person => person.Id);
    a = a.filter((person) => -1 === idsInB.indexOf(person.Id));
}
```

All you need to do now is call `cleanA` whenever the contents of `b` changes.

**Full working example:**

```js
interface Person {
  Id: number;
  Name: string;
}

let a: Person[] = [
    { Id: 1, Name: "John" },
    { Id: 2, Name: "Peter" },
    { Id: 3, Name: "Phillip" },
    { Id: 4, Name: "Abby" },
    { Id: 5, Name: "Don" },
];

let b: Person[] = [
    { Id: 1, Name: "John" },
    { Id: 4, Name: "Abby" },
];

function cleanA(): void {
    let idsInB: number[] = b.map(person => person.Id);
    a = a.filter((person) => -1 === idsInB.indexOf(person.Id));
}


presentArray(a, 'A before clean');
cleanA();
presentArray(a, 'A after clean');

// -------------------------------------------------------
// Displaying purposes only:
// -------------------------------------------------------

function presentArray(arr, msg) {
    document.body.innerHTML += `<br><b>${msg}:</b><br>[<br>`
    + arr.map(person => `&nbsp;&nbsp;{ Id: ${person.Id}, Name: ${person.Name} },<br>`)
         .join('')
    + ' ]<br><br>';
}
```

Comment: its working fine in plain javascript, but if i put in a typescript - angular project it wont...

Comment: Runtime logic isn't any different in Typescript. But yes, you'll possibly have to define some types in this code.

Comment: @PeterSmith I have added some typings to the snippet. Maybe they will help you out.